# Formula parse error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Can someone explain to me why I am receiving this error?

The 'if' statement seems to look fine to me, but I am just a little unfamiliar with Google Spreadsheets and if there are syntax differences:

`=IF((D8) >= 2600 , "$1.39", IF((D8) < 2600 AND >= 2500, "$1.40", IF((D8) < 2500 AND >= 2400, "1.42", IF((D8) <2400 AND >= 2300, "$1.45", IF((D8) < 2300 AND >= 2200, "$1.50", IF((D8) < 2200 AND >= 2100, "$1.54", iF((D8) < 2100 AND >= 2000, "$1.60", iF((D8) < 2000 AND >= 1900, "$1.65", IF((D8) < 1900 AND >= 1800, "$1.72", IF((D8) < 1800 AND >= 1700, "$1.79", iF((D8) < 1700 , "NEED MORE MILES")))))))))))`

Comment: Does google sheets accept this format:  `(D8) < 2600 AND >= 2500` ?? Excel, for example, needs it to be: `AND( D8 < 2600, D8 >= 2500 )`

Comment: @pnuts: sorry, No what does not what? :) Are you saying No, google sheets doesn't take that format? or No, Excel doesn't need it to be like that ?  O.o  (sorry, my bad for putting 2 points in there ;) ) lol

Comment: @pnuts: I was just going to suggest that to him as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by pnuts in comments, use a lookup table:

1) setup the table (for example) in Cell A1-B14:

```
  Miles    Amount
  0        Need More Miles
  1700     1.79
  1800     1.72
  1900     1.65
  2000     1.6
  2100     1.54
  2200     1.5
  2300     1.45
  2400     1.42
  2500     1.4
  2600     1.39
  99999999
```

2) Assuming input is in cell H2.
put this formula in cell H3:
`=VLOOKUP(H2,$A$2:$B$13,2,TRUE)`

This takes the value in H2, and looks up a near match in the table, giving the amount as a result.

Hopefully you can adjust this to your specific needs.